# Laravel how to join tables and use where condition using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Lets say there are 2 tables:

videos (id, file_name)

matches (id, videos_id, match_number)

I want to get video file_name by match_number. I have read that using eloquent, you can avoid joins.

So I try various things from examples like this:

Video.php

```
class Video extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'videos';

    public function matches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Match', 'videos_id');
    }

    /*public function match()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Match', 'id');
    }*/

    /**
     * @param $matchNumber
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getByMatchNumber($matchNumber)
    {
        return $this
            ->matches()
            //->select('videos.file_name')
            //->limit(10)
            ->where('matches.match_number', $matchNumber)
            ->file_name;
             //   ->match()


    }
}
```

But nothing works.

I think I am assuming well that video hasMany matches because in reality there are many matches which have same video.

So how it should look?

**Update**

Match_number column is unique, like id. There cannot be multiple matches with same match number.
And there is only one video for one match. Limit(10) just was doing to try without where condition, to not get millions of results. 
But same video is assigned to many matches.

**Update:**

I remade the function based on the jedrzej.kurylo answer and fixed mistakes I assume - whereMatchNumber - such function will not be existing:

```
public function getByMatchNumber($matchNumber)
    {
       return Match::with('video')
            ->where('match_number', $matchNumber)->first(); //->video->file_name;



    }
```

But it does not work. I get error:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::video()

**Update**

In Match.php model I added relation:

```
public function video()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Video', 'videos_id');
    }
```

Still getting the same error:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::videos()

**Update:**
I had a mistake, was trying to add plural form when gettign error and forgot to undo:

```
return Match::with('videos')
```

needed:

```
return Match::with('video')
```

**Update**

Still not able to get result. I run this:

```
$video = $this->video->getByMatchNumber($this->matchNumber);

print_r($video->file_name);
```

I see good queries in query log:

```
 [1] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `matches` where `match_number` = ? limit 1
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 104439
                )

            [time] => 4.62
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [query] => select `file_name` from `videos` where `videos`.`id` in (?)
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1089
                )

            [time] => 37.24
        )
```

I executed last query with the binding in HeidySQL and result is found. So why $video->file_name could be empty?

**Update**

Also I tried

```
die($video->video->file_name);
```

and get error

**Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: You want to get a file name or video object by match number? Can be there multiple Matches with the same match_number? I can see you have both id and match_number in matches column so I'd assume match_number is not unique, otherwise it would be the key. You're also doing "limit(10)" which suggests there can be multiple videos for single match number.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo - updated question information

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using Eloquent is not about getting rid of joins, but about easier manipulation of data using object notation. Depending on how you use it you'll fetch data using joins or without joins. And there is nothing wrong about using joins, as long as they're used properly.

To achieve what you need, the easiest way would be to do:

```
$match = Match::with('video')->whereMatchNumber($number)->first();
if ($match) {
  echo $match->video->file_name;
}
```

This will however run 2 queries in your database. If you want to do that using one query, you'll need to use joins:

```
$match = Match::join('videos', 'matches.videos_id', '=', 'videos.id')->whereMatchNumber($number)->first();
if($match) {
  echo $match->file_name;
}
```

Comment: for me this does not work. I updated the question, what I tried. And so far I do not find it easier to manipulate data :)

Comment: You have too define relation to video in Match class. Do you have one? What is it called?

Comment: I did not have one, because I read in some blog that no need relations in both ways, but now I added. Updated the question.

Comment: Well, it's not needed if you don't use that, but here you obviously need one

Comment: No, now you're getting a different error about videos() method, not video(). Didn't you use 'videos' instead of 'video' in with()?

Comment: Yea, I noticed now that I wrote 'videos' when was not working, and forgot to undo to 'video'. So now it works. Looking at the syntax it looks that we join videos to match, instead of match to videos. While I wanted to take information from videos table, by default I take videos table and join matches to it.
Also checking query log - ir uses 'SELECT *' but I have heard that it is bad to use "SELECT *" and should use field names instead of *. What is good that I did not need to write long join line: ->join('matches', 'matches.videos_id', '=', 'videos.id')
Thanks.

Comment: If you do need all fiields you can list needed fields by passing an array of field names into first()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85172/discussion-between-darius-v-and-jedrzej-kurylo).